# Run a function when number of references decrease in shared_ptr

Tags: c++11, shared-ptr

I am developing a cache and I need to know when an object expired.
Is possible run a function when the reference counter of a shared_ptr decrease?

```
std::shared_ptr< MyClass > p1 = std::make_shared( MyClass() );
std::shared_ptr< MyClass > p2 = p1; // p1.use_count() = 2
p2.reset(); // [ run function ] p1.use_count() = 1
```

Answer (score 7):

You can't have a function called every time the reference count decreases, but you can have one called when it hits zero. You do this by passing a "custom deleter" to the `shared_ptr` constructor (you can't use the `make_shared` utility for this); the deleter is a callable object which is responsible for being passed, and deleting, the shared object.

Example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
using namespace std;

void deleteInt(int* i)
{
    std::cout << "Deleting " << *i << std::endl;
    delete i;
}

int main() {
    std::shared_ptr<int> ptr(new int(3), &deleteInt); // refcount now 1
    auto ptr2 = ptr; // refcount now 2
    ptr.reset(); // refcount now 1
    ptr2.reset(); // refcount now 0, deleter called
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can specify a deleter functor when creating the shared_ptr. The following article show an example use of a deleter:

- http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/shared_ptr

Answer (score 1):

Not using a vanilla `std::shared_ptr`, but if you *only* require customized behaviour when calling `reset()` (with no arguments), you can easily create a custom adapter:

```
template <typename T>
struct my_ptr : public std::shared_ptr<T> {
    using std::shared_ptr<T>::shared_ptr;

    void reset() {
        std::shared_ptr<T>::reset(); // Release the managed object.

        /* Run custom function */
    }
};
```

And use it like this:

```
my_ptr<int> p = std::make_shared<int>(5);
std::cout << *p << std::endl; // Works as usual.
p.reset(); // Customized behaviour.
```

### Edit

This answer is meant to suggest a solution to an issue that I didn't think the other answers did address, that is: executing custom behaviour every time when the refcount is decreased by use of `reset()`.

If the issue is simply to make a call upon object *release*, then use a custom deleter functor as suggested in the answers by [@Sneftel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27508389/873025) and [@fjardon](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27508377/873025).

Comment: That doesn't let you know when the refcount hits zero.

Comment: It also only works if the user calls `reset()` before the pointer goes out of scope.

Comment: @Sneftel Sure you can, just let your custom function access the current refcount e.g. using `std::shared_ptr::use_count`. And for comment #2: That is why I proclaimed exactly that requirement at the beginning of [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27510772/873025).

Comment: @Sneftel Just to be clear: the refcount will decrease when the `my_ptr` object goes out of scope, just as with a `std::shared_ptr`, it's only the custom function that will *not* get called.